# Command line HMAC calulation is different from Node.JS crypto.createHmac('sha256')

Tags: openssl, c++, qt, node.js

In Node.js I use following code

```
hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRET).update(fileContent).digest('hex');
```

to calculate HMAC. C++/Qt code analogue

```
QByteArray hash = QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(
           fileContent, SECRET, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();
```

produces same result as in Node.JS for a text JSON file content. However Linux command line HMAC calculation produces different hash code:

```
> openssl sha256 -hmac "SECRET" filename
```

What is wrong in command line? What are correct `openssl` arguments?

Comment: what are the hashes you get? what's the content of the file?

Comment: @ilkkachu I mentioned above - JSON text file content. You may run above code and command to check result on any text file and secret key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two commands give the same result if you give the same inputs. If you got different outputs then either one of your tools has a bug (which is pretty unlikely) or you didn't pass the same inputs. Note that:

- The `SECRET` should be a randomly generated key. Each byte of this key has a 1/256 chance of being 0. You cannot pass a null byte on a command line.
- The input of HMAC is a string of bytes. If the JavaScript code reads the input as text and changes its encoding or modifies its whitespace, it would result in a different MAC.
- In particular, check that you haven't added or removed a trailing newline.
- In particular, check that you haven't changed between Unix and Windows line endings.

Comment: Yes, written small node.js example to read the file - got same results. Probably difference in whitespaces or newline.